# #REF! (Reference does not exist) error after sort

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm probably making a really simple mistake here but I can't figure it out. I'm making a simple spreadsheet that tracks runners' last 5k time and then I take their time away from the slowest runner to give a 'handicap' time. This way all the runners should finish the race together next time.

Here's the data:
[image]

And the formula is

```
= MAX(D2:D16) - D2
```

When I do a sort (by the calculated start time column, I get the #REF! error (Reference does not exist. Like I say it's probably really simple, but I can't figure it out. Any help appreciated!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

The formula you are using in `F2` should be `=MAX(D$2:D$16)-D2`, otherwise it won't even work when you drag it down. And sorting it with from the menu obviously won't do anything, since if it's a formula you dragged down, it will autoupdate to still use the same row from column `D`. There is however a `sort` function you can use either in a different column (like in `G2` `=sort(F2:F16,1,1)`) or you could change your `F2` formula to `=SORT(ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(D$2:D$16)-D2:D16),1,1)`, so both sorting and propagation down the column are done in one.